# hidden field in code behind not refreshing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

//  problem refreshing value
  code behind file dynamically creates a checkbox, aspx file contains javascript that is invoked
when the checkbox is checked see below:

//javascript

```
function checkBoxClicked(sender) 
{
  var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('hcompare');

  if (sender.checked == true) {
     sCompareAuditVersion = sender.value;
     }
        document.getElementById('hcompare').value = sCompareAuditVersion;
}
```

//aspx file -
 I have used a hidden field to pass to code behind file and have initialize value with 'x' to
//ensure that value changes

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="lowSectionClass">
   <asp:HiddenField id="hcompare" value="X"  runat="server">
    </asp:HiddenField>
```

//code behind file dynamically builds chekbox

```
public class Report : Page
    {
    protected HiddenField hcompare; 

    private string populateCalculations(int tabID, int programID, int participantID)
      {
        string str = "";
        str = ((((str + "<br /><br /><center><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='10'>" + "<tr class='HeadingCellText'>") + "<td>Audit Version</td>" + "<td></td>") + "<td>Calculation Set</td>" + "<td></td>") + "<td>Run Calcs/Print Report/Print CSB</td>" + "<td></td>") + "<td>Compare?</td>" + "</tr>";
        DataTable infoList = new DataTable();
        infoList = new ReportClass().GetInfoList(programID);
        if (infoList.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < infoList.Rows.Count; i++)  // 1 = a audit, 2 = b audit, 3 = c audit.....
            {
                if ((i % 2) == 0) //audit 'a' = 0, audit 'b' = 1
                {
                        str = string.Concat(new object[] { str, "<td>", infoList.Rows[i]["dtCalcDate"], "</td>" }) + "<td></td>";
                       str = string.Concat(new object[] { str, "<td><a href=\"javascript:runCalcs('", programID, "','", infoList.Rows[i]["sAuditVersion"].ToString(), "');\">Run Calcs</a> | <a href=\"javascript:setPrintVariables(", programID, ",", participantID, ",'", 
                            infoList.Rows[i]["sAuditVersion"].ToString(), "');section_CallBack('build');\">Print Report</a> | <a href=\"ReportViewer.aspx?ProgramID=", programID, "&ParticipantID=", participantID, "&AuditVersion=",
                            infoList.Rows[i]["sAuditVersion"].ToString(),"&CompareAuditVersion=", hcompare.Value,"&csb=1\" target='blank'>Print CSB</a></td>"
                         }) + "<td></td>";
    // above is where the hidden field is assigned to be passes in as a parameters and the value is not being updated
    // below is where the checkbox is created and assigned function 'checkBoxClicked(this)'
                       str = string.Concat(new object[] { str, "<td><input id='Checkbox", i, "' tabindex='", i, "' value='", infoList.Rows[i]["sAuditVersion"].ToString(), "' onclick='checkBoxClicked(this)' type='checkbox' /></td>" }) + "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                }
              return (str + "</tfoot>" + "</table></center>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the id really hcompare?

Answer (score 1):

Set clientidmode = static for your hidden field

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="lowSectionClass">
<asp:HiddenField id="hcompare" value="X" clientIdMode="static" runat="server">
</asp:HiddenField>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Or alternatively, use `document.getElementById('<%= hcompare.ClientID %>')` in your script.

Comment: I have tried using 'static' no luck, and also used ('<%=hcomapre.clientID %>') and no luck either. I need to be able to refresh the value of "hcompare.value"